# Regression validation score doesn't look good

Tags: python, testing, scikit-learn, regression, training-data

I have a problem. When you have a look at the first photo, you can see the validation score isn't good-looking.
When I comment out this line `plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")` you can see the training plot perfectly.
Why does the val looks so huge?

```py
dfListingsFeature_regression = pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coderanker3/dataset4/main/listings_cleaned.csv")
d = {True: 1, False: 0, np.nan : np.nan} 
dfListingsFeature_regression['host_is_superhost'] = dfListingsFeature_regression[
                                                             'host_is_superhost'].map(d).astype('int')

X = dfListingsFeature_regression.drop(columns=['host_id', 'id', 'price']) # Features
y = dfListingsFeature_regression['price'] # Target variable
print(dfListingsFeature_nor.shape)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def plot_learning_curves(model, X, y):
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    train_errors, val_errors = [], []
    for m in range(1, 1000 + 1):
        model.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict = model.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_val_predict = model.predict(X_val)
        train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], y_train_predict))
        val_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict))

    plt.figure( figsize=(20,20))
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(train_errors), "r-+", linewidth=2, label="train")
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
    plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
    plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)          

lin_reg = LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True,n_jobs=1, normalize=True)
plot_learning_curves(lin_reg, X, y)
#plt.axis([0, 80, 0, 3])                       
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with unstable? the validation score will be decreasing as the model better learns to generalize the data.

Comment: well maybe you are right, i corrected the word unstable. And yes thats correct. i want o see the decrease aswell as the increase of the model when it understands what to do. But in the first graph i cant ready anything usefull out of it while the second graph clearly shows the red line increasing. I want to optimize the view of the first picture. That would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a [logarithmic scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) on the y axis

```
plt.yscale("log")
```

or combine it with removing RMSE values below certain quantile to better visualize

```
import numpy as np

# Remove errors beyon 80% quantile
val_errors_quantile = np.array(val_errors)[np.where(val_errors < np.quantile(val_errors, 0.8))]

plt.figure( figsize=(12,12))
plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors_sample), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")
plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

which results in better interpretation of the RMSE value decreasing

[image]

If you have other ideas of how to scale it you can pass a [custom function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale) to `plt.yscale`